# How WAL flush the data into disk?

Tags: database, postgresql, wal

In WAL file, if we don't keep the actual data with Insert/Update commands, how will we get the data in a new fresh DB by applying the WAL file?

If some data is updated in diskblock in memory and wal file also update but then crash happen how WAL we replay the query to restore ?

Comment: Data is included in the WAL logs. WAL stands for Write Ahead Log, which means(roughly) the Postgres server  writes the actions and data to the log first, then to the to the actual database files. You should read [WAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/wal-intro.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does PostgreSQL need both WAL buffer and WAL segment file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75605292/why-does-postgresql-need-both-wal-buffer-and-wal-segment-file)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot recover the database data from WAL into a new, fresh database. This is precisely because, as you describe, WAL does not store SQL statements, but physical modifications to data files.

You can use WAL to recover only in combination with a *base backup*, which is a copy of the physical database files. If you don't have a base backup, there is no need to archive WAL segments, except perhaps for a standby server to catch up from.

Comment: setting wal_level to `logical` doesn't store enough info to recover the database ? From the doc `In logical level, the same information is logged as with replica, plus information needed to extract logical change sets from the WAL`, what does mean information needed to extract logical change sets ? Does it refer to the corresponding query `insert`, `update` or `delete` executed in the database ?

Comment: @OlivierBoissé Imagine you have an empty database and along comes a decoded `UPDATE` statement. It wouldn't find a row to update.

Comment: if you start from the very beginning of the wal, there will be necessarily an `insert` before the `update` statement

Comment: @OlivierBoissé Very true. But can you imagine how log it would take to recover a busy database that has been running for years that way? And how much WAL you'd have to retain?

Comment: does that means WAL files are automatically removed after some time to prevent having too many logs ?

Comment: @OlivierBoissé Yes, WAL isn't kept forever. You need a regular physical base backup.